# Exporting a tibble to csv

Tags: r

I am trying to write my tibble to a csv file. I did this once before but I can't remember for the life of me how I did it. Everything I've read seems to point to the fact that `write.csv` should work. However, I can't seem to get it to write to the file. Here is my current code:

```
  odd = subset(adult_pref_1, adult_pref_1$profile == "odd")
  odd |>
  # Perform the next task separately for each subject
  group_by(subject) |>

  # Run the correlation tests
 mutate(estimate = cor.test(rating, mean_p)$estimate,
         pvalue = cor.test(rating, mean_p)$p.value) |> 

  # Remove irrelevant columns
  select(subject, estimate, pvalue) |> 

  distinct(subject, .keep_all = TRUE)|>
  group_by(odd$estimate) %>%
      mutate(pt1 = (1 + (estimate)/(1 - (estimate)))) |>
      mutate(z = .5 * ln(pt1)) |>
      write.csv(odd, path = "/Users/scahalan/Documents/odd_rate_mean_corr.csv")
```

When I run this, I receive the error below:

```
 Error in utils::write.table(mutate(group_by(distinct(select(mutate(group_by(odd, : 
unused argument (path = "/Users/scahalan/Documents/odd_rate_mean.csv")
```

So, I'm entirely sure where I'm going wrong. I know I've done it before but I feel like I'm missing a step somewhere. Any help would be great. Thank you!

Comment: If you look at the `?write.csv` help page, you'll see the argument name is `file` not `path`.

Comment: Try `file = ` instead of `path = `

Comment: Also, since you're piping in with `|>`, don't put `odd` in the command--let the piped handle it: `... |> write.csv(file = "/Users/scahalan/Documents/odd_rate_mean_corr.csv")`

Comment: That solved it! I'm still getting used to ```tidy verse``` and sometimes forget it plays by a slightly different set of rules. Thank you